# Clear a silverlight tree view with hierarchy

Tags: silverlight, treeview

I have a tree view In a SL 4 application that I build dynamically via a WCF method. The tree view consists of Folders and documents. I need to be able to rebuild the tree when batches of documents are added.

How to you clear all of the items from a SL treeview?, and don't say `TreeView.Items.Clear()` because that does not work. It also impossible to use a `foreach` loop to remove all items and their children. I say an article [here](http://forums.silverlight.net/p/52874/137432.aspx), but don't see a `TreeView.Children.Copy` or a `TreeView.Items.Copy` anywhere. This is the last thing I've tried, and I'm at a loss...

Please let me know if you know a way to get this done... Thanks!

```
Private Sub NewDocumentTree_Received(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GetDocumentTreeCompletedEventArgs)
        Me.ThisDocTreeView = e.Result
        ClearTree()
        PopulateDocTreeView()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ClearTree()
        Dim tempTree As New TreeView()
        tempTree = CopyTreeViewToNewObject(Me.docTreeView)
        For Each tvi As TreeViewItem In tempTree.Items
            For Each sub_tvi As TreeViewItem In tvi.Items
                For Each d_tvi As TreeViewItem In sub_tvi.Items
                    RemoveTreeViewSubItems(d_tvi)
                Next
                RemoveTreeViewSubItems(sub_tvi)
            Next
            RemoveTreeViewSubItems(tvi)
        Next
        tempTree.UpdateLayout()

        Me.docTreeView = tempTree
        Me.docTreeView.UpdateLayout()
    End Sub

    Private Sub RemoveTreeViewSubItems(ByVal tvi As TreeViewItem)
        For Each sub_tvi As TreeViewItem In tvi.Items
            tvi.Items.Remove(sub_tvi)
            tvi.UpdateLayout()
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Function CopyTreeViewToNewObject(ByVal treeview As TreeView) As TreeView
        Dim newTree As New TreeView()
        For Each Parent As TreeViewItem In treeview.Items
            newTree.Items.Add(GetTreeViewItemAndChildren(Parent))
        Next
        Return newTree
    End Function

    Private Function GetTreeViewItemAndChildren(ByVal treeViewItem As TreeViewItem)
        Dim ParentalItem As New TreeViewItem
        ParentalItem = treeViewItem
        For Each child As TreeViewItem In treeViewItem.Items
            Dim firstChild As New TreeViewItem
            firstChild = child
            For Each subChild As TreeViewItem In child.Items
                Dim secondChild As New TreeViewItem
                secondChild = child
                firstChild.Items.Add(secondChild)
            Next
            ParentalItem.Items.Add(firstChild)
        Next

        Return ParentalItem
    End Function
```

UPDATE: Here is the method that receives notification from my WCF service of a batch update to the tree, and the primary method that builds the tree view.

```
    Private Sub NewDocumentTree_Received(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GetDocumentTreeCompletedEventArgs)

        Me.ThisDocTreeView = e.Result

        Me.docTreeView.Items.Clear()

        Me.docTreeView.UpdateLayout()

        PopulateDocTreeView()

    End Sub

Private Sub PopulateDocTreeView()

        'ensure all items are clear
        Me.docTreeView.Items.Clear()

        'loop through root folder to extract parent "user" folders, and examine sub folders
        For Each folder As PortalOnline.PortalDocRootFolder In ThisDocTreeView.RootFolders

            'get this users folder as a tree view items
            Dim parent As TreeViewItem = GetParentTreeViewFolder(folder)

            'define a new list of category folders based on this users documents
            Dim catFolders As List(Of TreeViewItem) = GetCategoryFolderList(folder)

            'loop through the subfolders of the users parent folder for document and get each document folder
            'as a new tree view item
            For Each child As PortalOnline.PortalDocInfo In folder.SubFolders

                'define the document tree view item
                Dim childItem As TreeViewItem = GetDocumentTreeItem(child, folder)

                'loop through the category folders, and add the document tree view item to the appropriate folder
                For Each categoryfolder As TreeViewItem In catFolders

                    Dim childMeta As DocTreeViewItem = childItem.Tag

                    'if the category tree veiw item head matches the document category of the document tree view item
                    'then add the document tree view item into that category folder
                    If categoryfolder.Header = childMeta.DocumentCategory Then

                        categoryfolder.Items.Add(childItem)

                    End If

                Next

            Next

            'add all category folders to the users parent folder
            For Each subfolder As TreeViewItem In catFolders

                parent.Items.Add(subfolder)

            Next

            'add the users parent folder to the tree view
            docTreeView.Items.Add(parent)

        Next

    End Sub
```

The treeview is obviously being populated when the page loads, and the NewDocumentTree_Received Method is called when WCF Publishes and update.

The ERROR in the instance:
"An Items with the same key has alread been added"

Which tells me the tree is not being cleared and updated, or else the tree wouldn't populate in the first place... hopefully the help clarify the situation.

Comment: NOTE* The PopulateTreeView() Method starts off with a Me.docTreeView.Items.Clear()

Comment: Could you explain why `treeView.Items.Clear()` doesn't work?  Does it give errors, not clear all items, or what?  I put together a quick test and it seemed to work for me.

Comment: Sure.. When I call treeView.Items.Clear() absolutely nothing happens. I've also tried treeView.Items.UpdateLayout() after words... still nothing. It's a simple as that.

Comment: I also want to add that it's a tree view with 3 levels of hierarchy... @Luke In your test, were you able to clear the entire tree by simply using treeview.items.clear() ?? AND able to re-populate the tree with modified data?? If so, please post your code.

Comment: I was able to clear the tree, and re-populate it with modified data.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the way I built the TreeView so I am using TreeView.ItemsSource and assigning a list of TreeViewItems to that. I then use the TreeView.ClearValue(TreeView.ItemsSourceProperty) method to clear the tree, and then repopulate it with a new items source.. that seems to get the job done.

```
Me.docTreeView.ClearValue(TreeView.ItemsSourceProperty)

Me.docTreeView = New TreeView

Me.docTreeView.ItemsSource = Nothing

PopulateDocTreeView()
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce any problem with `TreeView.Items.Clear()`.  Below is the code I added to a new Silverlight Application project in Visual Web Developer Express:

MainPage.xaml (contents of root `<UserControl>` element):

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Content="1" Click="Button1_Click" />
    <Button Content="2" Click="Button2_Click" />
    <sdk:TreeView x:Name="docTreeView" />
</StackPanel>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs (below `MainPage()` constructor):

```
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<TreeViewItem> items3 = new List<TreeViewItem>() { new TreeViewItem() { Header = "1.b.i" }, new TreeViewItem() { Header = "1.b.ii" }, new TreeViewItem() { Header = "1.b.iii" } };
        List<TreeViewItem> items2 = new List<TreeViewItem>() { new TreeViewItem() { Header = "1.a" }, new TreeViewItem() { Header = "1.b" }, new TreeViewItem() { Header = "1.c" } };
        items3.ForEach(item => items2[1].Items.Add(item));
        List<TreeViewItem> items1 = new List<TreeViewItem>() { new TreeViewItem() { Header = "1" }, new TreeViewItem() { Header = "2" }, new TreeViewItem() { Header = "3" } };
        items2.ForEach(item => items1[0].Items.Add(item));

        docTreeView.Items.Clear();
        items1.ForEach(item => docTreeView.Items.Add(item));
    }

    private void Button2_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<TreeViewItem> items3 = new List<TreeViewItem>() { new TreeViewItem() { Header = "TWO.B.I" }, new TreeViewItem() { Header = "TWO.B.II" }, new TreeViewItem() { Header = "TWO.B.III" } };
        List<TreeViewItem> items2 = new List<TreeViewItem>() { new TreeViewItem() { Header = "TWO.A" }, new TreeViewItem() { Header = "TWO.B" }, new TreeViewItem() { Header = "TWO.C" } };
        items3.ForEach(item => items2[1].Items.Add(item));
        List<TreeViewItem> items1 = new List<TreeViewItem>() { new TreeViewItem() { Header = "ONE" }, new TreeViewItem() { Header = "TWO" }, new TreeViewItem() { Header = "THREE" } };
        items2.ForEach(item => items1[1].Items.Add(item));

        docTreeView.Items.Clear();
        items1.ForEach(item => docTreeView.Items.Add(item));
    }
```

One thing you haven't shared is the XAML you use to show your TreeView.  You haven't by any chance, bound the `ItemsSource` of the treeview within your XAML to something, have you?  (I say this because you mention that calling `ClearValue` on `ItemsSourceProperty` appears to fix things for you, and this suggests to me that there is a binding on that property.  However, my understanding is that the rest of your code assembles the tree in code-behind by assigning to the `Items` property.)

---

Incidentally, the following loop (in `RemoveTreeViewSubItems`) will not work, unless  `tvi.Items` is already empty:

```
    For Each sub_tvi As TreeViewItem In tvi.Items
        tvi.Items.Remove(sub_tvi)
        tvi.UpdateLayout()
    Next
```

You cannot remove items from a collection as you are iterating over it.  If you try to do so, you will get an 'Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object' error.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, Items.Clear() would hang my application. I fixed it with the code below. It removes each item starting from the child and works its way up.

```
    private void ClearFix()
    {
            RemoveKids(this.Items);
    }

    private void RemoveKids(ItemCollection ItemsColl)
    {
        foreach (object obj in ItemsColl.ToArray())
        {
            TreeViewItem tvi = obj as TreeViewItem;

            if (tvi == null)
                continue;

            if (tvi.HasItems)
                RemoveKids(tvi.Items);

            this.Items.Remove(tvi);
        }
    }
```

Notice I had to use ItemColl.ToArray() because you will get an error if you change the collection that you are iterating over.

Not sure if this added to the problem, but I was not actually using TreeViewItem, but an object that was inherited from it.